# Merging JSONB values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Using the `||` operator yields the following result:

```
select '{"a":{"b":2}}'::jsonb || '{"a":{"c":3}}'::jsonb ;
    ?column?     
-----------------
 {"a": {"c": 3}}
(1 row)
```

I would like to be able to do achieve the following result (`??` just a  placeholder for the operator):

```
select '{"a":{"b":2}}'::jsonb ?? '{"a":{"c":3}}'::jsonb ;
    ?column?     
-----------------
 {"a": {"b": 2, "c": 3}}
(1 row)
```

So, you can see the top-level `a` key has its child values "merged" such that the result contains both `b` and `c`.

How do you "deep" merge two **JSONB** values in Postgres?

Is this possible, if so how?

---

A more complex test case:

```
select '{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"z":true}}'::jsonb ?? '{"a":{"b":{"d":4},"z":false}}'::jsonb ;
    ?column?     
-----------------
 {"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": 4}, "z": false}}
(1 row)
```

Another test case where a primitive "merges over" and object:

```
select '{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"z":true}}'::jsonb ?? '{"a":{"b":false,"z":false}}'::jsonb ;
        ?column?         
-----------------
 {"a": {"b": false, "z": false}}
(1 row)
```

Comment: This might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/166092/1822

Comment: jsonb_set can merge or can destroy: `jsonb_set('{"a":{"x":1},"b":2}'::jsonb, '{a,y}', '1'::jsonb);` will merge object `{"y":1}`  with object `{"x":1}` ... But `jsonb_set('{"a":{"x":1},"b":2}'::jsonb, '{a}', '{"x":1}'::jsonb);` will destroy! replacing full old object by the new one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should merge unnested elements using `jsonb_each()` for both values. Doing this in a non-trivial query may be uncomfortable, so I would prefer a custom function like this one:

```
create or replace function jsonb_my_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select 
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(ka, kb), 
            case 
                when va isnull then vb 
                when vb isnull then va 
                else va || vb 
            end
        )
    from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va)
    full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb
$$;
```

Use:

```
select jsonb_my_merge(
    '{"a":{"b":2}, "d": {"e": 10}, "x": 1}'::jsonb, 
    '{"a":{"c":3}, "d": {"f": 11}, "y": 2}'::jsonb
)

                          jsonb_my_merge                          
------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"a": {"b": 2, "c": 3}, "d": {"e": 10, "f": 11}, "x": 1, "y": 2}
(1 row)
```

---

You can slightly modify the function using recursion to get a solution working on any level of nesting:

```
create or replace function jsonb_recursive_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select 
        jsonb_object_agg(
            coalesce(ka, kb), 
            case 
                when va isnull then vb 
                when vb isnull then va 
                when jsonb_typeof(va) <> 'object' then va || vb
                else jsonb_recursive_merge(va, vb)
            end
        )
    from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va)
    full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb
$$;
```

Examples:

```
select jsonb_recursive_merge( 
    '{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"x":5}}'::jsonb, 
    '{"a":{"b":{"d":4},"y":6}}'::jsonb);

             jsonb_recursive_merge              
------------------------------------------------
 {"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": 4}, "x": 5, "y": 6}}
(1 row)

select jsonb_recursive_merge(
    '{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":1}}}}}'::jsonb, 
    '{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"f":2}}}}}'::jsonb)

            jsonb_recursive_merge             
----------------------------------------------
 {"a": {"b": {"c": {"d": {"e": 1, "f": 2}}}}}
(1 row)
```

---

Finally, the variant of the function with changes proposed by OP (see the comments below):

```
create or replace function jsonb_recursive_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb) 
returns jsonb language sql as $$ 
select 
    jsonb_object_agg(
        coalesce(ka, kb), 
        case 
            when va isnull then vb 
            when vb isnull then va 
            when va = vb then vb
            when jsonb_typeof(va) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(vb) <> 'object' then vb 
            else jsonb_recursive_merge(va, vb) end 
        ) 
    from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va) 
    full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb 
$$;
```

Comment: I've tried this function using a more complex object:

`select jsonb_my_merge(
    '{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"x":5}}'::jsonb, 
    '{"a":{"b":{"d":4},"y":6}}'::jsonb
);`

and the result it returned was 

`{"a": {"b": {"d": 4}, "x": 5, "y": 6}}`

what I'd like it return is

`{"a": {"b": {"c":3, "d": 4}, "x": 5, "y": 6}}`

instead

Comment: ... actually, I just encountered a scenario where this breaks:

`select jsonb_recursive_merge( 
    '{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"z":true}}'::jsonb, 
    '{"a":{"b":{"d":4},"z":false}}'::jsonb);`

yields 

`{"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": 4}, "z": [true, false]}}`

... but I'd expect it not to create that array, and instead yield this:

`{"a": {"b": {"c": 3, "d": 4}, "z": false}}`

Comment: `create or replace function jsonb_recursive_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
 select 
  jsonb_object_agg(
   coalesce(ka, kb), 
   case 
    when va isnull then vb 
    when vb isnull then va 
    when jsonb_typeof(va) <> 'object' then vb
    else jsonb_recursive_merge(va, vb)
   end
  )
 from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va)
 full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb
$$;`

What do you think of this? It's the same except when type not equals object `then va || vb` becomes `then vb`

Comment: I think it's ok. You are free to modify the function to meet your expectations. Your variant seems quite logical, maybe more than the original.

Comment: BTW, I have found another edge case,where an object is merged over by a primitive (see qn update)

`create or replace function jsonb_recursive_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
 select 
  jsonb_object_agg(
   coalesce(ka, kb), 
   case 
    when va isnull then vb 
    when vb isnull then va 
    when (jsonb_typeof(va) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(vb) <> 'object') then vb
    else jsonb_recursive_merge(va, vb)
   end
  )
 from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va)
 full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb
$$;`

Minor change required to the function ^

Comment: Yes, the condition should be symmetrical because of `full join`. I've added your variant to the answer.

Comment: Another special case to be handled: when both objects are empty, the result will be null instead of empty.

Example:

    `select jsonb_merge('{"type": {}}'::jsonb, '{"type": {}}'::jsonb)`


will result in `{"type": null}`

We can add this condition to the function to make it work properly:
`when va::text = '{}'::text and vb::text = '{}'::text then vb`

Comment: @MasterKiller - I've added a slightly simpler condition, see the updated answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

This kind of "deep merge" can be interpreted quite differently, depending on your use case. For completeness, my intuition usually dictates the following rules:

- **object + object**: Every property survives from each object, which is not in the other object (JSON's `null` value is considered to be *in* the object, if it's explicitly mentioned). When a property is in both objects, the merge continues recursively with the same rules (this point is usually agreed on).
- **array + array**: The result is the concatenation of the two arrays.
- **array + primitive/object**: the result is the first array, with the second JSON value appended to it.
- **any other cases**: The result is the second JSON value (so f.ex. primitives or incompatible types override each other).

---

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge_deep(jsonb, jsonb)
  returns jsonb
  language sql
  immutable
as $func$
  select case jsonb_typeof($1)
    when 'object' then case jsonb_typeof($2)
      when 'object' then (
        select    jsonb_object_agg(k, case
                    when e2.v is null then e1.v
                    when e1.v is null then e2.v
                    else jsonb_merge_deep(e1.v, e2.v)
                  end)
        from      jsonb_each($1) e1(k, v)
        full join jsonb_each($2) e2(k, v) using (k)
      )
      else $2
    end
    when 'array' then $1 || $2
    else $2
  end
$func$;
```

This function's added bonus is that it can be called with literally any type of JSON values: always produces a result & never complains about JSON value types.

http://rextester.com/FAC95623

Comment: Thank you pozs, realy nice solution. Not sure if it's a bug or this is how it is intended to work, but your function **returns a NULL** in case if the **second jsonb arg is null**, which leads to unwanted result. This effect is caused by the second CASE block where you are checking the type of the second jsonb arg. If it's other than 'object' it returns itself as is (NULL in our case). Returning the first arg fixes this issue.
https://diffy.org/diff/b6e18c9258d98

Answer (score 4):

Combining (merging :-D) answers from @klin, @pozs and comment from @Arman Khubezhov while also actually merging arrays instead of concatenating (which resulted in duplicates otherwise), came up with the following function:

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge_deep(jsonb, jsonb)
  returns jsonb
  language sql
  immutable
as $func$
  select case jsonb_typeof($1)
    when 'object' then
      case jsonb_typeof($2)
        when 'object' then (
          select jsonb_object_agg(k,
             case
               when e2.v is null then e1.v
               when e1.v is null then e2.v
               else jsonb_merge_deep(e1.v, e2.v)
             end
          )
          from jsonb_each($1) e1(k, v)
          full join jsonb_each($2) e2(k, v) using (k)
          )
        else COALESCE($2, $1)
      end
    when 'array' then
      (
        SELECT jsonb_agg(items.val)
        FROM (
          SELECT jsonb_array_elements($1) AS val
          UNION
          SELECT jsonb_array_elements($2) AS val
        ) AS items
      )
    else $2
  end
$func$;
```

Based on comment from @Arman Khubezhov, enhanced the case when any of $1 or $2 is null with:

```
    else COALESCE($2, $1)
```

And added real merge (no duplicate) of the 2 arrays values with:

```
when 'array' then
  (
    SELECT jsonb_agg(items.val)
    FROM (
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements($1) AS val
      UNION
      SELECT jsonb_array_elements($2) AS val
    ) AS items
  )
```

Glad if one can come up with a enhanced code for this one - like an existing PostreSQL function I am not aware of?

---

Pros: no data loss when combining 2 JSONB values or updating a JSONB field in an UPDATE query like.

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_jsonb_field = jsonb_merge_deep(my_jsonb_field, '{ "a": { "aa" : { "aaa" : [6, 4, 7] } } }'::jsonb)
```

Cons: removing a key/value or array value requires a dedicated query.

Answer (score 3):

After PostgreSQL 9.5 you can use `jsonb_set` function:

1. `'{a,c}'` looking into path if it is not there, it will created.
2. `'{"a":{"c":3}}'::jsonb#>'{a,c}'` this will get the value of c

> new_value added if create_missing is true ( default is true)

Hier is document [jsonb -functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

```
select jsonb_set('{"a":{"b":2}}', '{a,c}','{"a":{"c":3}}'::jsonb#>'{a,c}' )

Result:  {"a":{"c":3,"b":2}}
```

Merge more attribute at once:

```
with jsonb_paths(main_part,missing_part) as (
values ('{"a":{"b":2}}','{"a":{"c":3,"d":4}}')
)
select jsonb_object_agg(t.k,t.v||t2.v)
from jsonb_paths,
jsonb_each(main_part::jsonb) t(k,v),
jsonb_each(missing_part::jsonb) t2(k,v);

result: {"a":{"c":3,"b":2,"d":4}}
```

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of using the jsonb_set function. H/w this means that I would (a) need to know/ specify the path that needs to be merged, and (b) can only merge one attribute at a time.

Comment: Tried this second query that you've added with more complex values: `with jsonb_paths(main_part,missing_part) as (
 values ('{"a":{"b":{"c":3},"x":5}}','{"a":{"b":{"d":4},"y":6}}')
)
select jsonb_object_agg(t.k,t.v||t2.v)
from jsonb_paths,
jsonb_each(main_part::jsonb) t(k,v),
jsonb_each(missing_part::jsonb) t2(k,v);`

result was `{"a": {"b": {"d": 4}, "x": 5, "y": 6}}`

result I would like is `{"a": {"b": {"c":3, "d": 4}, "x": 5, "y": 6}}` 

... so it looks like it only handles one level of depth.

Comment: Right, `jsonb_set` won't work if one or more parents don't exist. I think it will only create a key if the parent is an object and the key doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 2):

As @lightSouls say, after PostgreSQL 9.5 you can use `jsonb_set()` function... But you must to learn how to use it!

### `jsonb_set` can merge or destroy...

Supposing `j:='{"a":{"x":1},"b":2}'::jsonb`.

- `jsonb_set(j, '{a,y}', '1'::jsonb);` will **merge** object `{"y":1}`  with object `{"x":1}`. 
  Result: `{"a": {"x": 1, "y": 1}, "b": 2}`
- `jsonb_set(j, '{a}', '{"x":1}'::jsonb);` will **destroy**! replacing full old object by the new one.
  Result: `{"a": {"x": 1}, "b": 2}`