# postgresql - query to build up json

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

Running: PostgreSQL 9.6.2

I have data stored in a table that is in the form of a key/value pair.  The "key" is actually the path of a json object, each one being a property.  So for example if the key was "cogs","props1","value", then the json object would be like so:

```
{
  "cogs":{
     "props1": {
       "value": 100    
      }
  }
}
```

I'd like to somehow reconstruct a json object via a SQL query if possible.  Here is the test data set:

```
drop table if exists test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
    id serial,
    file_id integer NOT NULL,
    key character varying[],
    value character varying,
    status character varying
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","description"}', 'some awesome cog', 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","display"}', 'Giant Cog', null);
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props1","value"}', '100', 'not verified');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props1","id"}', 26, 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props1","dimensions"}', '{"200", "300"}', null);
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props2","value"}', '200', 'not verified');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props2","id"}', 27, 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"cogs","props2","dimensions"}', '{"700", "800"}', null);

insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","description"}', 'some awesome widget', 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","display"}', 'Giant Widget', null);
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props1","value"}', '100', 'not verified');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props1","id"}', 28, 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props1","dimensions"}', '{"200", "300"}', null);
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props2","value"}', '200', 'not verified');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props2","id"}', 29, 'approved');
insert into test_table (file_id, key, value, status)
values (1, '{"widgets","props2","dimensions"}', '{"900", "1000"}', null);
```

The output I'm looking for is in this format:

```
{
    "cogs": {
        "description": "some awesome cog",
        "display": "Giant Cog",
        "props1": {
            "value": 100,
            "id": 26,
            "dimensions": [200, 300]
        },
        "props2": {
            "value": 200,
            "id": 27,
            "dimensions": [700, 800]
        }
    },
    "widgets": {
        "description": "some awesome widget",
        "display": "Giant Widget",
        "props1": {
            "value": 100,
            "id": 28,
            "dimensions": [200, 300]
        },
        "props2": {
            "value": 200,
            "id": 29,
            "dimensions": [900, 1000]
        }
    }
}
```

Some issues I'm facing:

1. The "value" column can hold text, numbers, and an array.  For whatever reason, the server-side code using knex.js is storing an array of integers (ie, [100,300]) into postgres as the following format: {"100","300"}.  I need to ensure I extract this out as an array of integers as well.
2. Trying to make this dynamic as possible.  Maybe a recursive procedure to figure out what depth of the "key" path exists.... rather than hard-coding array lookup values.
3. json_object_agg works well to group together properties into a single object.  However it breaks when hitting a null value.  So if the "key" column has only two values (ie, "cogs","description"), and I attempt to aggregate up an array of length three (ie, "cogs","props1","value"), it will break unless I filter on only arrays of length 3.
4. Preserve the ordering of the input.  @klin solution below is amazing and gets me 95% of the way there.  However I failed to mention to also preserve the ordering...

Comment: please - version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dynamic solution needs some work.

First, we need a function to convert a text array and a value to a jsonb object.

```
create or replace function keys_to_object(keys text[], val text)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
declare
    i int;
    rslt jsonb = to_jsonb(val);
begin
    for i in select generate_subscripts(keys, 1, true) loop
        rslt := jsonb_build_object(keys[i], rslt);
    end loop;
    return rslt;
end $$;

select keys_to_object(array['key', 'subkey', 'subsub'], 'value');

              keys_to_object              
------------------------------------------
 {"key": {"subkey": {"subsub": "value"}}}
(1 row)
```

Next, another function to merge jsonb objects (see [Merging JSONB values in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954907/1995738)).

```
create or replace function jsonb_merge(a jsonb, b jsonb) 
returns jsonb language sql as $$ 
select 
    jsonb_object_agg(
        coalesce(ka, kb), 
        case 
            when va isnull then vb 
            when vb isnull then va 
            when jsonb_typeof(va) <> 'object' or jsonb_typeof(vb) <> 'object' then vb 
            else jsonb_merge(va, vb) end 
        ) 
    from jsonb_each(a) e1(ka, va) 
    full join jsonb_each(b) e2(kb, vb) on ka = kb 
$$;

select jsonb_merge('{"key": {"subkey1": "value1"}}', '{"key": {"subkey2": "value2"}}');

                     jsonb_merge                     
-----------------------------------------------------
 {"key": {"subkey1": "value1", "subkey2": "value2"}}
(1 row)
```

Finally, let's create an aggregate based on the above function,

```
create aggregate jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb)
(
    sfunc = jsonb_merge,
    stype = jsonb
);
```

and we are done:

```
select jsonb_pretty(jsonb_merge_agg(keys_to_object(key, translate(value, '{}"', '[]'))))
from test_table;

                 jsonb_pretty                 
----------------------------------------------
 {                                           +
     "cogs": {                               +
         "props1": {                         +
             "id": "26",                     +
             "value": "100",                 +
             "dimensions": "[200, 300]"      +
         },                                  +
         "props2": {                         +
             "id": "27",                     +
             "value": "200",                 +
             "dimensions": "[700, 800]"      +
         },                                  +
         "display": "Giant Cog",             +
         "description": "some awesome cog"   +
     },                                      +
     "widgets": {                            +
         "props1": {                         +
             "id": "28",                     +
             "value": "100",                 +
             "dimensions": "[200, 300]"      +
         },                                  +
         "props2": {                         +
             "id": "29",                     +
             "value": "200",                 +
             "dimensions": "[900, 1000]"     +
         },                                  +
         "display": "Giant Widget",          +
         "description": "some awesome widget"+
     }                                       +
 }
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm drinking a cold one in your name this evening!  Amazing that this works!  Clearly I have much to learn :)

Comment: Is it possible to preserve the row ordering during the aggregation?  I've been reading up on custom aggregates and still a bit confused by it, thus my reply here.

Comment: Unfortunately not. By the JSON definition a collection of name/value pairs is unordered. To store ordered list of values you should use JSON array. Vide [json.org](http://www.json.org/json-en.html). Postgres JSONB does not guarantee any order in a json collection.

Comment: However, you can try to use json instead of jsonb. Replace `jsonb` with `json` in the whole script and remove `jsonb_pretty()` (this function has no json equivalent). The order of objects should remain as in the table, this is undocumented feature of the json type though.

Comment: Made these changes and can confirm that it definitely preserved order!  How great.  Read up on a lot of this and it seems JSON type performs worse than JSONB... however in my case it's un-noticeable.  Thank you for your help!