# Convert flattened key/value table into hierarchical JSON in PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with unique key/value pairs, which were originally in a JSON format, but have been normalized and melted:

```
key             | value
-----------------------------
name            | Bob
address.city    | Vancouver
address.country | Canada
```

I need to turn this into a hierarchical JSON:

```
{
"name": "Bob",
"address": {
    "city": "Vancouver",
    "country": "Canada"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this easily within SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) almost does everything for you, but unfortunately it can only create missing leafs (i.e. missing last keys on a path), but not whole missing branches. To overcome this, here is a modified version of it, which can set values on any missing levels:

```sql
create function jsonb_set_rec(jsonb, jsonb, text[])
  returns jsonb
  language sql
as $$
  select case
    when array_length($3, 1) > 1 and ($1 #> $3[:array_upper($3, 1) - 1]) is null
    then jsonb_set_rec($1, jsonb_build_object($3[array_upper($3, 1)], $2), $3[:array_upper($3, 1) - 1])
    else jsonb_set($1, $3, $2, true)
  end
$$;
```

Now you only need to apply this function one-by-one to your rows, starting with an empty json object: `{}`. You can do this with either [recursive CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```sql
with recursive props as (
   (select   distinct on (grp)
             pk, grp, jsonb_set_rec('{}', to_jsonb(value), string_to_array(key, '.')) json_object
    from     eav_tbl
    order by grp, pk)
  union all
   (select   distinct on (grp)
             eav_tbl.pk, grp, jsonb_set_rec(json_object, to_jsonb(value), string_to_array(key, '.'))
    from     props
    join     eav_tbl using (grp)
    where    eav_tbl.pk > props.pk
    order by grp, eav_tbl.pk)
)
select   distinct on (grp)
         grp, json_object
from     props
order by grp, pk desc;
```

**Or**, with a custom aggregate defined as:

```sql
create aggregate jsonb_set_agg(jsonb, text[]) (
  sfunc    = jsonb_set_rec,
  stype    = jsonb,
  initcond = '{}'
);
```

your query could became as simple as:

```sql
select   grp, jsonb_set_agg(to_jsonb(value), string_to_array(key, '.'))
from     eav_tbl
group by grp;
```

https://rextester.com/TULNU73750

Comment: Wow, thanks for this really elegant solution!

In case this is of benefit to others -- in my actual table I had some values that were lists stored as text like "['one', 'two', 'three']". To make this solution work for that also, I replaced the instances of `to_jsonb(value)` with `CASE substring(value, 1, 1) WHEN '[' THEN to_jsonb(pylist_to_array(value)) ELSE to_jsonb(value) END`, where pylist_to_array is a custom function that converts this kind of TEXT to a TEXT[].

Answer (score 2):

There are no ready to use tools for this. The function generates a hierarchical json object based on a path:

```
create or replace function jsonb_build_object_from_path(path text, value text)
returns jsonb language plpgsql as $$
declare
    obj jsonb;
    keys text[] := string_to_array(path, '.');
    level int := cardinality(keys);
begin
    obj := jsonb_build_object(keys[level], value);
    while level > 1 loop
        level := level- 1;
        obj := jsonb_build_object(keys[level], obj);
    end loop;
    return obj;
end $$;
```

You also need the aggregate function `jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb)` described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143226/1995738) The query:

```
with my_table (path, value) as (
values
    ('name', 'Bob'),
    ('address.city', 'Vancouver'),
    ('address.country', 'Canada'),
    ('first.second.third', 'value')
)

select jsonb_merge_agg(jsonb_build_object_from_path(path, value))
from my_table;
```

gives this object:

```
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "first":
    {
        "second":
        {
            "third": "value"
        }
    },
    "address":
    {
        "city": "Vancouver",
        "country": "Canada"
    }
}
```

The function do not recognize json arrays.

Comment: Thanks so much for this excellent solution @klin! I really wish I could accept two solutions, as this does the job really well also. I picked the other one because I was easily able to modify it to create JSON arrays as well, without digging deeper into the generic functions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really think of something simpler, although I think there should be an easier way.

I assume there is some additional column that can be used to bring the keys that belong to one "person" together, I used `p_id` for that in my example.

```
select p_id, 
       jsonb_object_agg(k, case level when 1 then v -> k else v end) 
from (
  select p_id, 
         elements[1] k, 
         jsonb_object_agg(case cardinality(elements) when 1 then ky else elements[2] end, value) v, 
         max(cardinality(elements)) as level
  from (       
    select p_id, 
           "key" as ky, 
           string_to_array("key", '.') as elements, value
    from kv 
  ) t1
  group by p_id, k
) t2
group by p_id;
```

The innermost query just converts the dot notation to an array for easier access later.

The next level then builds JSON objects depending on the "key". For the "single level" keys, it just uses key/value, for the others it uses the second element + the value and then aggregates those that belong together.

The second query level returns the following:

```
p_id | k       | v                                          | level
-----+---------+--------------------------------------------+------
   1 | address | {"city": "Vancouver", "country": "Canada"} |     2
   1 | name    | {"name": "Bob"}                            |     1
   2 | address | {"city": "Munich", "country": "Germany"}   |     2
   2 | name    | {"name": "John"}                           |     1
```

The aggregation done in the second step, leaves one level too much for the "single element" keys, and that's what we need level for.

If that distinction wasn't made, the final aggregation would return `{"name": {"name": "Bob"}, "address": {"city": "Vancouver", "country": "Canada"}}` instead of the wanted: `{"name": "Bob", "address": {"city": "Vancouver", "country": "Canada"}}`.

The expression `case level when 1 then v -> k else v end` essentially turns `{"name": "Bob"}` back to `"Bob"`.

---

So, with the following sample data:

```
create table kv (p_id integer, "key" text, value text);
insert into kv
values
(1, 'name','Bob'),
(1, 'address.city','Vancouver'),
(1, 'address.country','Canada'),
(2, 'name','John'),
(2, 'address.city','Munich'),
(2, 'address.country','Germany');
```

then query returns:

```
p_id | jsonb_object_agg                                                      
-----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | {"name": "Bob", "address": {"city": "Vancouver", "country": "Canada"}}
   2 | {"name": "John", "address": {"city": "Munich", "country": "Germany"}}
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/SJOTCD7977

Comment: Thank you a_horse_with_no_name. This is the best solution that doesn't require any new functions to be created. Unfortunately, it also only works the two levels.. if more than 2 levels exist, the 2nd level key acquires the value from one of the bottom levels.

Comment: @maciej: arcadio's answer can be written without creating the views. Just use common table expressions instead `with v_kv as (...), v_datos as (...) select ...`

Comment: yup, but you still need to hardcode the elements (name, address, etc.) Not sure how this could be generalized.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table kv (key text, value text);
```

```
insert into kv
values
('name','Bob'),
('address.city','Vancouver'),
('address.country','Canada'),
('name','John'),
('address.city','Munich'),
('address.country','Germany');
```

```
create view v_kv as select  row_number() over() as nRec, key, value from kv;
```

```
create view v_datos as
    select k1.nrec, k1.value as name, k2.value as address_city, k3.value as address_country
    from v_kv k1 inner join v_kv k2 on (k1.nrec + 1 = k2.nrec)
        inner join v_kv k3 on ((k1.nrec + 2= k3.nrec) and (k2.nrec + 1 = k3.nrec))
    where mod(k1.nrec, 3) = 1;
```

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('name',name, 'address', json_build_object('city',address_city, 'country', address_country)))
    from  v_datos;
```

Comment: Thanks Arcadio, this is useful for a simple case where the structure of the data is known. Unfortunately, my data is more complex and unpredictable.