# How to add elements to array in jsonb by key (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

This query

```
SELECT '{"a": 1, "b": [{"x": "y"}]}'::jsonb || '{"b": [{"a": "b"}]}'::jsonb
```

returns

```
"{"a": 1, "b": [{"a": "b"}]}"
```

But I need

```
"{"a": 1, "b": [{"x": "y"}, {"a": "b"}]}"
```

How can this be done?
PG 9.5

Comment: Use the function described in this post: [Merging JSONB values in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954907/1995738)