# Simply way to append a key-value pair in Postgres JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to write an UPDATE statement to add key-values pairs to a nested JSON path.

Right now my method is to use a CASE statement. For example, if I wanted to add the key-value pair {key: val} into the path a->b1...

```
UPDATE orders SET info = jsonb_set(info, '{a}',                                                -- adds to the a->b1 key (chain created if not exists)
    CASE
    WHEN info->'a' IS NULL THEN '{"b1": {"key": "val"}}'
    WHEN info->'a'->'b1' IS NULL THEN jsonb_set(info->'a', '{b1}', '{"key": "val"}', true)
    ELSE jsonb_set(info->'a', '{b1}', info->'a'->'b1' || '{"key": "val"}', true)
    END,
    true);
```

The statement above works...

- If a doesn't exist, it'll create a with {b1: {key: val}}.
- If a->b1 doesn't exist, it'll create a->b1 and set it to {key: val}.
- If a->b1 does exist, it'll grab a->b1 and append {key: val} within it.

, but it's tedious to write and understand. Does Postgres provide an easier way to do what I'm trying to do? Given a path, I want to add one or more key-value pairs into it (creating the objects in the path if they don't yet exist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function described in [Merging JSONB values in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42954907/1995738)

```
update orders 
set info = jsonb_recursive_merge(info, '{"a": {"b1": {"key": "val"}}}');
```

[Test it in rextester.](https://rextester.com/MSV42600)

Comment: Thank you. The only issue with the func is that if a value already exists, it merges it with the new value into an array. I've changed the function to overwrite the value by replacing 'va || vb' with just 'vb'. For example, if I want to merge in {a: {b: c:{key:newval}}} but a->b->c->key already points to oldval, the merged value would be [oldval,newval]. With this change, it'll get replaced to just oldval.

Comment: @offbynull - Indeed, merging of multilevel json objects may be interpreted in various ways. You can also try a simple concatenation operator `||`.